# Gradle DSL method not found: complie() only with jopendocument

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm trying to use Gradle with this 'org.jopendocument:jOpenDocument:1.3b1' a obtain this Error:

this Gradle file (1) fail with this error:

```
Error:(21, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'complie()'

Possible causes:

The project '' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.

Open Gradle wrapper 

file The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

---

Gradle file (1)

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'

    ..//
    compile 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:1.1.7'
    complie 'org.jopendocument:jOpenDocument:1.3b1'

}
```

but add this one to test `compile 'org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.scr.annotations:1.9.12'` and it works well

Gradle file (2)

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'

    ..//
    compile 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:1.1.7'
    //complie 'org.jopendocument:jOpenDocument:1.3b1'
    compile 'org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.scr.annotations:1.9.12'
}
```

but want to use complie 'org.jopendocument:jOpenDocument:1.3b1', does not work, I have dealt with:

- 'org.jopendocument:jOpenDocument:1.3b1'
- 'org.jopendocument:jOpenDocument:1.3'
- 'org.jopendocument:jOpenDocument:1.+'
- 'org.jopendocument:jOpenDocument:1.1'

but it does not work, someone can tell me if I'm doing something wrong

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jopendocument/jOpenDocument/1.3b1
http://repo.gradle.org/gradle/repo/org/jopendocument/jOpenDocument/1.3/

Comment: complie != compile. Voting to close as simple typographical error.

Comment: @JBNizet If you believe, I can delete the question? and sorry for this stupid question

Comment: Yes, you can delete the question.

Comment: @JBNizet not problem but, one cuestion de user mofr loses points?

Comment: No, he won't lose any point.

Comment: @JBNizet will not let me delete it says to send you a flag to the moderator, it may be because it is in the stack to close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a typing mistake: you need `compile`, but not `complie`.

That line in first gradle file:
`complie 'org.jopendocument:jOpenDocument:1.3b1'`